# How to recover deleted messages from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have accidentally deleted messages from the Facebook Messenger app which I want to recover. These messages are very important to me. Please guide me on how I can recover them as I have tried all available options out there.

Or there is a way to talk to Facebook team as they don't respond to emails now?

Answer (score 1):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/540897679352879):

> No, you can't see deleted messages or conversations. Deleting a message permanently removes it from your Chat list.

> Keep in mind that deleting a message or conversation from your Chat list won't delete it from the Chat list of the person you chatted with.

The only option is, ask the person you had conversation to forward those messages/conversation history to you.